# Android UI: Multiple Horizontally Paged Table

Tags: android, user-interface, landscape, tablelayout

I am trying to implement a UI that contains a data table (populated dynamically) displayed using a `TableLayout`.  I would like 4 columns of the table to be displayed by default, with the ability to horizontally scroll the table to reveal 4 (or more) additional columns.  Is this possible using a `TableLayout` combined with a horizontal/vertical `ScrollView`?  I would appreciate any example XML exhibiting this style.

Here is an example to clarify:

**Default table view**
[image]

**View after scrolling to right**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I went about solving this was by using a `ViewFlipper`.  I am rather surprised no one had mentioned this before.

I changed my XML around to look like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:id="@+id/hsv1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/dataTableFlipper"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/dataTable"
                            android:stretchColumns="*">
                </TableLayout>
                <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/dataTable2"
                            android:stretchColumns="*">
                </TableLayout>
        </ViewFlipper>
</ScrollView>
```

This way I could manage each page of the table as separate `TableLayouts`.

Declaring the `ViewFlipper`programmatically allowed me to use `ViewFlipper.showNext()` to alternate between the two tables.  Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this by placing your TableLayout inside a HorizontalScrollView.  Define the width of your elements inside your TableLayout

Something like this  (i did not test this):

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/hsv1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
           android:gravity="center" 
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
           android:id="@+id/tl1" 
           android:scrollbars="horizontal">

        // Your other elements go here.

    </TableLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: This looks good, but I did mention I am adding the elements dynamically (in my activity class).  How can I specify the width of an element that is being added by programmatically creating a TextView and adding it to the TableLayout?

Comment: @Ben Silver: just set the table's `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`, and let the dynamic insertion of table rows cause it to stretch.  `HorizontalScrollView` should handle the rest.

Comment: I still haven't managed to get this to work, all of the columns in my data table are scrunched together, here's my XML file: http://pastebin.com/j7KuGtbM.  If you have the time to look at it, see if you can spot an error.  Sorry, I'm very new to XML and Android.  Here is how my UI looks with this layout: http://imgur.com/UcBkX

Comment: @Ben Silver - a few things:  not sure you need the LinearLayout surrounded the ScrollView.  That could potentially cause problems.  Also, you have an outer ScrollView containing the inner HorizontalScrollView.  As per google, you shouldn't put one scrollview inside another.  Find another way to do that.  So, try just having the HorizontalScrollView and then the TableLayout and nothing else.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @SBerg413 Thanks, I really appreciate the help.  I incorporated all of your suggestions so that I just have the TableLayout wrapped in a HorizontalScrollView.  The UI still looks identical to the previous picture I linked.  I think I am going to have to find an alternate solution.  Thanks for taking the time, however.

Comment: @Ben Silver - no problem.  Just a note - you still need to size the table columns, which it doesn't look like you're doing.  You can either do this with a specific width or use padding and/or margins to get the appropriate width.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this directly solves your problem, but do take a look at android-viewflow on github. 
https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow